# Styling Android ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I want to show custom animation in my `ProgressDialog`. After reading few posts, I understood that we can define custom styles in styles.xml and provide our own custom drawable there. But, when I am trying to define styles for `ProgressDialog`, it is not allowing me to do so. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
< style parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressDialog" name="MyProgressDialog"> 

< item name="android:progressDrawable">@anim/myanim < /item> 

< /style>
```

It does not understand `Widget.ProgressDialog`. What is the difference between `ProgressBar` and `ProgressDialog` if I put `ProgressBar` in Spinner mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use styles to make a custom progress dialog. Making a [custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) is quite easy when you inflate it from an xml layout.

Comment: Thanks Romain!! Let me try it.